# Difference between object and companion object and how to test them

Tags: kotlin

I have a data class `PersonRecord`. But the data I receive from an API has different form, I need to process it in order to extract A.

1. The first solution consist of creating a data class `PersonForm` to represent the API-data and then create an independent function that take into parameters an instance of class `PersonForm` and returns an instance of class `PersonRecord`.

Looking at some stackoverflow posts, I have also found the following solutions :

2.

```kotlin
data class PersonRecord(val name: String, val age: Int, val tel: String){       
    object ModelMapper {
        fun from(form: PersonForm) = 
            PersonRecord(form.firstName + form.lastName, form.age, form.tel)           
    }
}
```

3. Same as two but with companion object instead of object.

**Is there a way that is more idiomatic/efficient/natural etc ? In which context, each one is preferred ?**

Thanks.

Comment: It’s just a matter of preference. 2 is going to require your usage site to be very verbose. Option 4 is to write an extension function of PersonForm called `toPersonRecord()`. Succinct and easy to use. The status as an extension function makes more sense for code organization than making it a member function or part of a companion or inner object since it deals with the specifics of another class.

Comment: Option 3 is definetely better that option 2 (there will be only one instance of this inner object regardless of amount of `PersonRecord` instances). Also, it's more idiomatic to call it `of`, not `from`. Option 4, suggested by @Tenfour04 is good too (note, that it inverse dependency between these classes).

Answer (score 1):

The most idiomatic/natural way is creating secondary constructor:

```kotlin
data class PersonRecord(val name: String, val age: Int, val tel: String) {
    constructor(form: PersonForm) : this(form.firstName + form.lastName, form.age, form.tel)
}
```

Comment: This method have some limitations I guess. If I had to do some more advanced computation (instead of just concatenating strings), it will fill less natural. Am I right?

Comment: You may call any accessible function in constructor delegation call: `constructor(form: PersonForm) : this(f(form.firstName, form.lastName), form.age, form.tel)`. So, you may extract logic of your advanced computations into a private file-local function or companion object method. If you need to do even more complex computations (with some dependency between values of several parameters, passing into another constructor), then choose option 1; is also rather idiomatic (however note, that it's not java-interop friendly)

Comment: Of course, answers to this question are opinion. I didn't mention this fifth option in my comment because it creates tighter coupling between the classes, and therefore is inferior to option 1 (my opinion of course). The code that has to know everything about both classes is now inside one of those classes. Not a big deal either way since with IDE shortcuts, it won't affect the difficulty of code maintenance. I don't think I would call this idiomatic since none of the standard library classes I've encountered are designed this way. They are designed like option 4 from my comment.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Do you mind elaborating on the meaning of "tighter coupling between the classes? and why this is bad? How the option 4. prevents this coupling? Moreover, Is there some libraries you could suggest and from which I can learn some design principles in Kotlin? Thanks for sharing ^_^

Comment: https://blog.ndepend.com/programming-coupling/ In this case, it could be debatable whether "option 4" reduces coupling since essentially the same code still exists. I think it potentially aids in maintainability since the code that relies on both classes is isolated away from those two classes so it's not part of their contracts.

Comment: @Tenfour04 any recommendations of places to read **good-quality** Kotlin code?

Comment: @LivBanana the standard library code, or the open source projects from Square/CashApp on GitHub.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks ! I took a look, it seems overwhelming. I don't know what to pick first. Is there a specific source code that is beginner-friendly ?